# How can I make a PDF with text that no one can copy?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I want to make this block content read-only in the PDF output, so that no one can copy it:

```
<fo:block font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="10pt"  space-before="4pt" text-align="left">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-size="12pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/personal/name"/>
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: How would that work? XLS-FO is a text markup language, which means that you can simply open the file with any text editor. You can use whatever markup you want, but if the user can access the markup source they can do whatever they want with the content.

Comment: Thanks Ken, Is there any way to protect data? I mean user can only read but can't copy I need to implement this in one of my PDF file.

Comment: The PDF file can allow you to protect text against being copied, but that's not in XSL-FO or XSLT. That's part of the PDF format, and AFAIK applies to the entire document and not just a single element in the text. But your question makes no mention of a PDF file that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AH Formatter, for example, you could put the text in a PDF layer for which printing and export is disabled and the layer is locked.  See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#pdf-layer

However, I don't see how you would stop someone taking a screenshot or somebody typing what they read on the screen into a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to block text permanently from copy only temporarily in some conformant viewers such as Acrobat or partners. (The base file will be editable in other application/pdf s) Here is an example

### No functions are allowed

[image]

### Same File different Browser everything is allowed,

(subject to availability in a browser (all are editors) near your clients location.)
[image]

### First Browser again

(after file is unlocked, because the locks are optional) Do not think that increasing security level will make any difference, if the file is public on the web for viewing in a PDF viewer (thus word editor) it can be copied or reprinted and if images only then OCR.

[image]